# Set XMLDataProvider source dynamically

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xmldataprovider

While all examples and sources I found is to set the resource in XAML statically, I would only know in run time the name of the XML file to be connected with XMLDataProvider. Is there a way to set  either in code behind or in XAML?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="XMLFoo" Source="Foo.xml" XPath="Foo"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

It could be Foo.xml, or could be Goo.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can change that while runtime. Unfortunately you cannot bind it, so you have to do stuff in Code-Behind.

Here's a simple example:

```
(this.Resources["XMLFoo"] as XmlDataProvider).Source = new Uri("Goo.xml");
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to have just one instance of `XamlDataProvider` and would like your source to change dynamically, I don't think it is possible in pure XAML as you cannot bind to [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider.source%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property, since that is not a `DependencyProperty`.

From code-behind, you can get the instance your provider and change it's source.

```
var provider = (XmlDataProvider) Resources.FindName("XMLFoo");
provider.Source = new Uri("bar.xml", UriKind.Relative);
```

Alternatively, you can use MVVM and expose your `XmlDataProvider` as a property on the ViewModel and bind it to your View, you can then change the `Source` and refresh data from the ViewModel itself.